# how to maintain data consistency in listview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a app that displays data in a listview using baseadapter. The user is able to click a element in the listview and it takes the user to a page where they can edit the data that is being displayed on that element. When the user clicks back it takes the user to the listview however the changes are not updated. How can i update the listview once the user clicks back.

Comment: firstly update the stored the data then call notifySetDataChanged in onResume()

Comment: Where have you stored the data that is being displayed in listview ? Post your code too for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think just set your adapter in onResume() method, so each and everytime you should go to on that screen, each and everytime it will refresh your Adapter.

Comment: @pratik- would that cause the listview to be re-drawn?

Comment: yes but before setting it, you can check whether its already drawn or not, if drawn then make it null and then set

Comment: @pratik- is there a way to do it without it being re-drawn. I dont want the listview to flicker when it re draws because i have images in the listview

Comment: @Samantha Then whatever data you want to get, just get it in background and then do notifyDataSetChanged(), it will work